# Alexa skills events not firing when hosted in web service

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have custom skill that calls web service i created. I am able to launch and get other intent, but i am not getting notification when permission for notification is changed by user of my skill. I need he notification event to get user id for sending push notifications later by other service.

Below is my json file:

```
{
  "manifest": {
    "apis": {
      "custom": {
        "endpoint": {
          "uri": "https://pathToMyService",
          "sslCertificateType": "Wildcard"
        },
        "interfaces": []
      }
    },
    "events": {
      "publications": [
         { "eventName": "AMAZON.TrashCollectionAlert.Activated" },
         { "eventName": "AMAZON.MessageAlert.Activated" }
       ],
       "subscriptions": [
         { "eventName": "SKILL_PROACTIVE_SUBSCRIPTION_CHANGED" },
         { "eventName": "SKILL_ENABLED" },
         { "eventName": "SKILL_DISABLED" },
         { "eventName": "SKILL_PERMISSION_ACCEPTED" },
         { "eventName": "SKILL_PERMISSION_CHANGED" },
       ],
       "regions": {
         "NA": {
           "endpoint": {
             "uri": "https://pathToMyService",
             "sslCertificateType": "Wildcard"
           }
         }
       },
       "endpoint": {
         "uri": "https://pathToMyService",
         "sslCertificateType": "Wildcard"
       }
     },
     "manifestVersion": "1.0",
     "permissions": [
       { "name": "alexa::devices:all:notifications:write" }
     ],
     "publishingInformation": {
       "locales": {
         "en-US": { "name": "Test Events" }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Below is the Launch request: I have truncated applicatioId, userID, consentToken, deviceId, apiAccessToken

{"version":"1.0","session":{"new":true,"sessionId":"amzn1.echo-api.session.60ad1e76-0872-4e10-b79d-7144cdf3e1c9","application":{"applicationId":"amzn1.ask.skill.59d60703"},"user":{"userId":"amzn1.ask.account.AGB7EOY","permissions":{"consentToken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1"}}},"context":{"System":{"application":{"applicationId":"amzn1.ask.skill.59d60703"},"user":{"userId":"amzn1.ask.account.AGB7EOY","permissions":{"consentToken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi"}},"device":{"deviceId":"amzn1.ask.device.AFNXDZOAEMFDFKK","supportedInterfaces":{}},"apiEndpoint":"https://api.amazonalexa.com","apiAccessToken":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1Qi"}},"request":{"type":"LaunchRequest","requestId":"amzn1.echo-api.request.adb318af-1977-4b36-b8ad-0bb4352fa563","timestamp":"2020-03-22T23:37:55Z","locale":"en-US","shouldLinkResultBeReturned":false}}

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue: When I updated by skill.json file using 
`ask api update-skill -s amzn1.ask.skill.59d6 -f Test.json` 
it didn't update properly. I noticed today when I got latest 
`ask api get-skill -s amzn1.ask.skill.59d6 >Test2.json` 
the event section was missing. I added back and reapplied and it's working now.